# Laravel: Database many to many with 3 models connected through a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-key-relationship, relationships

Laravel: Database many to many with 3 models connected through a pivot table.

I have the following database schema:

```
objects:
- id
- name

properties:
- id 
- name

values:
- id
- name

object_property_value_lists:
- id
- object_id
- property_id
- value_id
```

In my models, I have created the relationships between the elements.
The relationships are:

**Object.php**

```
public function properties()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\Property',
        'object_property_value_lists',
        'object_id',
        'property_id');
}
```

**Property.php**

```
public function values()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\Value',
        'object_property_value_lists', 
        'property_id', 
        'value_id');
}
```

Then I call:

```
$object = Object::with(array('properties','properties.values'))->find(1);
```

When I access the first relationship (properties), everything works find (it returns me the properties associated to the object. But when I call the 'value' relationship on the 'properties' elements, it returns every value connected to a property, not the only values related to properties for the specific object.

Any idea on how it would be possible to get only the specific values considering the current object and the current property?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your relationships (especially the one that's not working as intended)? Other then that - there is no need to call `->with('properties')` twice (once for properties, another time for properties + values). `Object::with('properties.values')->find(1)` is enough. This will load both properties and their values.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted the relationships